# MS-Access 2021 Adding/Subtracting field entry from one table with the current value in another

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm new to SQL and Access and am trying to take an entry from an InventoryTransactions.Quantity and summing it with another field from another table MasterInventory.QuantityOnHand. I know there is a way to do this with queries and forms but I'm kind of hitting a roadblock. Any help will be much appreciated!

Example

InventoryTransactions.Quantity (Table)

ID | TransactionItem | TransactionType | Quantity |

[ID] = Autonumber [TransactionItem] = Lookup referencing [.ID],[.ItemName], (Checking Y/N from [.Consumable]), all from [MasterInventory] [TransactionType] - Addition, Removal (Add, Subtract) from [TransactionTypeTable] Quantity - Number

MasterInventory

Here I want to add my record entry for Quantity in the above table and it to be added or subtracted (depending on the entry in the TransactionType field to .QuantityOnHand in this MasterInventory table

Say I've got 20 of something in [MasterInventory].[QuantityOnHand] and I enter 20 into the [ItemTransactions].[Quantity]

Saying that I selected "Addition" in [ItemTransactions].[TransactionType]

The new value in [MasterInventory].[QuantityOnHand] should now be updated to 40 for the corresponding [MasterInventory].[ID] field. (Updated to 0 if I selected "Remove" in [ItemTransactions].[TransactionType]

Let me know if you see this and need clarification please.

Comment: Use `DSUM()` function. Post sample data from your tables as text here.

Comment: Normally, saving calculated aggregate data is not best practice. Calculate quantity on hand from transaction records. Review http://allenbrowne.com/AppInventory.html

Comment: Thank you both. I'll research this. I've built a form that updates the quantity on hand pulling from item transactions and adding to master inventory. It's kind of buggy though and touchy with null values.